# HTML Editor for SharePoint 2013

Tags: html-editor

What is the best program to use for editing SharePoint 2013? I know Dreamweaver was good for 2003 but not sure what the best practice is now.

Answer (score 6):

Use whatever program you like for editing HTML -- Microsoft is putting a lot of effort into encouraging the use of whatever technology stack you already like with their products lately. As an aside (not really the point of the answer) I like to use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)!

If you need to edit aspx pages for SharePoint and use things like the `ScriptLink` control or create Add-ins I would recommend the [full versions of Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/) (including the free "Community" edition).

In addition to these though, you should still get SharePoint Designer, because you'll want to use it for editing workflows and may want to use it for editing aspx pages as well.

Comment: I have used both Dreamweaver and Designer to edit an html page.  With it being in Designer, there is no need to upload.

Comment: Sublime is also a good editor if you are using WebDAV

Answer (score 4):

[SharePoint Designer](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=35491) is the MS solution for this type of customization in SP 2013. Please note that WYSIWYG HTML capabilities are gone on the 2013 version. However, you can use [WebDAV](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-connect-to-a-sharepoint-site-using-webdav-sharepoint-2013) to map your site and use your favorite editor.